# How do I update a custom entity in crm 2011 online plugin code?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work in an 2011 online plugin? What I'm trying to do is update a collection of custom entities. It throws the following error on the service.Execute(...). Another way to achieve this much appreciated...

*Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): : System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.*

```
EntityCollection CustomEntitiesNeedingSync = service.RetrieveMultiple(RelevantCustomEntitiesQuery);

foreach (Entity currentCustomRecord in CustomEntitiesNeedingSync.Entities)
{
   UpdateRequest theUpdateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
   theUpdateRequest.Target = currentCustomRecord;
   service.Execute(currentCustomRecord);               
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to execute the request - not the record.

```
foreach (Entity currentCustomRecord in CustomEntitiesNeedingSync.Entities)
{
   UpdateRequest theUpdateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
   theUpdateRequest.Target = currentCustomRecord;
   service.Execute(theUpdateRequest);               
}
```

Comment: I checked my code and it was in the question where I made the mistake. What I did discover is that the exception gets thrown when I register the plugin as pre-validation. If I change it to pre-operation, no exception. I don't get why it wouldn't work at a pre-validation stage.

Comment: @keerz could you post more of your plugin? It's possible that you are requesting information which is not present (or not in the expected format) in this stage

Comment: @cekeller many thanks for helping. I have recoded how I did this and have ironed out a few issues. it now works as I hoped. I'll mark this as closed.